# Uploading documents from SharePoint to ProcessMaker

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload

In switching my team from the network drive to SharePoint, I need to ensure my users can continue to upload documents from a SharePoint library to Process Maker in the same way they are currently uploading documents from the network drive. Has anyone had any experience with this? I've read that Process Maker is designed to work with SharePoint but not sure how to set it up.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online allows you to sync your SharePoint Library with a folder on your local folder . Once you have mapped your SharePoint Library, you can save them on to it from Process Maker. The sync will automatically sync the changes\additions\deletions to SharePoint library .

The forum at [Process Maker Forum](https://forum.processmaker.com/viewtopic.php?t=730248) indicates they are not yet fully integrated from the product side directly. Hence ,the option I have suggested could be one way until they have fully integrated. My suggestion would be post a question to them about the things and get answers from team directly.

Comment: Thank you...good temporary solution. I'll send a message to the PM forum as well.